# Best way to set reactive form data coming from a list in Vue3 with Composition API?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

In Vue3 (Composition API) I have a form-component that needs to be filled with data, coming from a datalist-component. In the form-component do the following:

```
<input
  v-model="formdata.formfields.FirstName"
  type="text"
/>
<input
  v-model="formdata.formfields.LastName"
  type="text"
/>
  ...
  props: {
    fields: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({}), 
    },
  },
  setup(props, context) {
    const formdata = reactive({
      formfields: props.fields,
    });
    
    watch(
      () => props.fields,
      (current, previous) => {
        formdata.formfields= current;
      },
      { deep: true, immediate: true }
    );
```

Since it's not allowed to put props directly into the v-model, I introduced the `formdata` variable.

Then in the datalist-component I pass the fields to this form-component like this, with fields coming from an entry in the datalist:

```
    <dataform :fields="listitemfields" />
```

This works, but I find it a bit ugly. Instead of doing `formdata.formfields.FirstName` I would rather do this with `formfields.FirstName` only. But I can't seem to get `formfields` reactive in that way then.

The following doesn NOT work:

```
const formfields = reactive({});

watch(
  () => props.fields,
  (current, previous) => {
    formfields= current;
  },
  { deep: true, immediate: true }
);
```

Any ideas?

Is this even a good way to pass data like this to a form-component? I've looked into `emit` etc., but it seems even more complicated that way.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, `formfields` still holds a reference to the prop and mutates it.

This is commonly done by implementing two-way binding, i.e. a component accepts `modelValue` prop as input and emits `update:modelValue` as output. Prop and event name could be different but this way they conform `v-model`:

```
const formfields = reactive({});

watch(
  () => props.modelValue,
  (current) => {
    if (!deepEqual(formfields, current))
      Object.assign(formfields, current)
  },
  { deep: true, immediate: true }
);

watch(
  formfields,
  (current, previous) => {
    if (!deepEqual(current, previous))
      emit('update:modelValue', current)
  },
  { deep: true }
);
```

It depends on how the component is supposed to work. If input data is received only on mount and not supposed to be updated then the first `watch` could be replaced with `Object.assign(formfields, props.modelValue)`.